# How do I create TIMESTAMP (6) data_length 11 in Oracle table using CTAS?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I do create a table first it comes out right:

```
create table test (time timestamp(6));
```

Data_length = 11

```
"COLUMN_NAME" "DATA_TYPE"     "DATA_LENGTH"
"TIME"        "TIMESTAMP(6)"  11
```

But when I do CTAS:

```
 create table TEST as 
 select to_timestamp('09/09/17 04.07.25.086273', 'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss.FF6')  time  
 from dual;
```

The data length is 20:

```
 select column_name, data_type, data_length 
 from all_tab_columns 
 where  owner =user and table_name='TEST';

"COLUMN_NAME" "DATA_TYPE"     "DATA_LENGTH"
"TIME"        "TIMESTAMP(6)"  20
```

How do I get data_length = 11 in CTAS?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured one of the ways:

After CTAS run alter on time column:

```
alter table TEST modify(time TIMESTAMP);
```

It shrinks to 11 Bytes

```
 select column_name, data_type, data_length 
 from all_tab_columns 
 where  owner =user and table_name='TEST';

"COLUMN_NAME" "DATA_TYPE"     "DATA_LENGTH"
"TIME"        "TIMESTAMP(6)"  11
```

Comment: You may also want to specify the precision explicitly in the ALTER TABLE statement. The length 20 is for an External data type (not the native Oracle data type Timestamp). The External data type is called "Timestamp descriptor" and indeed it has length 20. And `TO_TIMESTAMP()` returns Timestamp descriptor, not Timestamp. (Don't ask me why, or what that means - ask Oracle!)